# React after posting new password for user can't log in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a big problem with updating user info with fetch PUT. When I do it everything seems to work correctly I even get encrypted password but then when I try to log in with data I changed it says it's incorrect. For example I change password to Admin123! it gets saved in MongoDB like this: $2b$10$w9h6TjiXcTeDHFVYLPoDzeRNqapnU4LE4geEGPk6D9sC.vsT/rjwm, but when I go to Login page it says password is incorrect. Before I update password it is also encrypted but I can log in without a problem. Could you please tell me what could couse this problem?

Here is React function for Updating user info:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Alert from "../elements/Alert";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function EditProfile() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [premium, setPremium] = useState("");
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const info = localStorage.getItem("user-info");
  const result = JSON.parse(info);

  const id = result._id;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      setEmail(result.email);
      setPassword();
      setName(result.name);
      setPhone(result.phone);
      setPremium(result.premium);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function update() {
    let user = password
      ? {
          name,
          email,
          password,
          phone,
          premium,
        }
      : {
          name,
          email,
          phone,
          premium,
        };

    console.log(user.password);

    let result = await fetch(`http://localhost:1234/api/users/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (result.status !== 200) {
      return setAlert(
        result.status + " " + result.statusText + " - Please check input fields"
      );
    }

    result = await result.json();

    if (result) {
      localStorage.removeItem("user-info");
      localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));
    }
    // history.push("/profile");
    // window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ minWidth: "70rem" }}>
      <h1 className="bigBar" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        Edit account
      </h1>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#f1f1f1",
          padding: "3rem",
          borderRadius: "1rem",
          marginBottom: "7rem",
        }}
      >
        <div style={{}}>
          {alert !== "" && (
            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Alert alert={alert}></Alert>
            </div>
          )}
          <div>
            <h6>User name</h6>
            <input
              autoFocus="autofocus"
              required="required"
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder={name}
              onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <br />

          <div>
            <h6>email</h6>
            <input
              required="required"
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder={email}
              onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <br />

          <div>
            <h6>Pasword</h6>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control"
              required="required"
            />
          </div>
          <br />

          <div>
            <h6>Phone</h6>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={e => setPhone(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control"
              required="required"
              placeholder={phone}
            />
          </div>
          <br />

          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <button onClick={update} className=" prettyB">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is PUT method from Node.js:

```
    router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateUser(req.body);
  if (error)
    //400 Bad request
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

  user.name = req.body.name;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.phone = req.body.phone;
  user.admin = req.body.admin;
  user.premium = req.body.premium;

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

  user = await user.save();

  if (!user)
    return res.status(404).send(`User with the given ID was not found`);

  res.send(user);
});
```

Logging in:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Alert from "../elements/Alert";

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  async function login() {
    let item = { email, password };

    let result = await fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/auth/user", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });

    console.log(result.status);

    if (result.status !== 200) {
      return setAlert(" Incorrect email or password");
    }

    await fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/auth", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
      });

    result = await result.json();

    if (result) localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));
    history.push("/");
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-sm-6" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1 className="bigBar">Login Page</h1>

      {alert !== "" && (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <Alert alert={alert}></Alert>
        </div>
      )}

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="email"
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="password"
        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="password"
      />

      <br />
      <button onClick={login} className="btn btn-primary">
        Sign up
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is method for posting new users, who also have encrypted passwords but when I create theese passwords this wya they work like a charm:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateUser(req.body);
  if (error)
    //   400 Bad request
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
  });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send(`User already registered`);

  user = new User(
    _.pick(req.body, [`name`, `email`, `password`, `phone`, `admin`, `premium`])
  );

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

  user = await user.save();
  const token = user.generateAuthenticationToken();

  res
    .header(`x-auth-token`, token)
    .send(_.pick(user, [`_id`, `name`, `email`]));
  user = await user.save();

  res.send(_.pick(user, [`_id`, `name`, `email`]));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic for updating is incorrect. I'd suggest these improvements

- Throws status 400 when user is **not** found.
- If user is found, keep it. Do not create new user
- Change its password from request body

```
      let user = await User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email,
      });
      if (!user) return res.status(400).send(`User not found`);

      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    
      user = await user.save();
```

Comment: Sorry, you are ofcourse right, I pasted the wrong method I meant to copy PUT. For my defense I really did spend a lot of time on this and I guess I was so exhausted I didn't think straight. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I just realised my mistake it's right here:
`user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);`
It should be:
`user.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);`